# Angular load custom controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller, angularjs-directive

Is it possible to load a custom controller specifying the filename each partial in angularjs?

Something like this:

```
 var demo = angular.module('demo', ['ngRoute', 'ui.bootstrap', 'demo.filters', 'demo.services', 'demo.directives', 'demo.controllers'])

    .config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {


        $routeProvider.when('/custom', 
                   {
                      templateUrl: 'partials/custom.html', 
                      controller:   customController.js
                    });

    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the way require js works you need to set your app up like this:

```
var demo = angular.module('demo', ['ngRoute', 'demo.filters', 'demo.services', 'demo.directives']);

demo.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    var _routes = ['/custom', '/custom2'];
    _routes.map(function(route) {
      var _cntrlName = route.slice(1, route.length);
      require([_cntrlName + "Controller"], function(controller) {
        $routeProvider.when(route, {
          templateUrl: '.' + route + '.html',
          controller: controller
        });
      });
    });
  }
]);
```

And your controller code must look like this:

```
define(function(require, exports, module) {
  function controller($scope) {
    $scope.testvar = "test 1!";
  }
  module.exports = controller;
});
```

Here is a plunker to demonstrate this http://plnkr.co/edit/N5fE5rezf6eM8jDIz23w?p=info

Comment: I tried your solution but unfortunatly it still not working http://plnkr.co/edit/WZaJDbSoAhf22G3iC5DL?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

Angular is not able to load JS files, but you can do this with [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/)

```
var demo = angular.module('demo', ['ngRoute', 'ui.bootstrap', 'demo.filters', 'demo.services',     'demo.directives'])

demo.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    var _routes = ['/custom', '/somepage']

    _routes.map(function(route){
        var _cntrlName = route.slice(1, route.length);
        $routeProvider.when(route,{
             templateUrl: 'partials' + route;
             controller: require('./' + _cntrlName + 'Controller.js');
        })     
    })  
});
```

Controller file:

```
(function(){
   function customController($scope){
       console.log($scope);   
   };
   return 'customController';  
)()
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need, but probably there are some mistakes in the code. Could you kindly provide to create a working fiddle? Thank you so much

Comment: Fixed the code, but i can't reproduce this on fiddle, there is no file system.

Comment: ..it doesn't work yet, and the error is the same on my main project. http://plnkr.co/edit/RfRFPq2OVNr5I6iGVtdq?p=preview

Comment: Later today i do it localy and give you link to repository.

Comment: you should try using plunker

Answer (score 0):

Instead of specifying a file put the controller's name.
However, you should remove ng-controller directive from your partial.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. you can load the other controller scope inside a different controller.

**Sample Code**:
var mode = angular.module().config(function(){

**controller("controllerName",{$scope : scope});** // This line is important

});